# Gitlab: How to collect raw log into artifact?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I was wondering if it is possible to collect the "raw" log file into an artifact in Gitlab ci?

I have tried to ask this on Gitlab forum but no answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by retrieving the raw log the job and adding it as an artifact. Be sure to retrieve it at the end of your job so the whole output will be in it.

Example:

`wget -O raw_log.txt https://gitlab.com/user/project/-/jobs/$CI_JOB_ID/raw`

The environment variable `$CI_JOB_ID` is automatically set by Gitlab.

Comment: Hi..just tried that and it did not work. I'm using powershell for my shell in gitlab-ci.yaml file. So that whould lead me to use $env:CI_JOB_ID.
wget -O raw_log.txt https://gitlab.com/user/project/-/jobs/$env:CI_JOB_ID/raw

Comment: Yeah, this should technically work (make sure you replace the place holders in the url and have wget installed). Though I'm not sure if it depends on the OS, whether Gitlab sets the $CI_JOB_ID variable. I'd recommend creating a new CI stage for this, using a Linux container.

Comment: What place holder do you refer to and what should I replace them with?

Comment: I refer to the placeholders used in the url: these are `user` and `project`. You need to replace them with the owner of the project and the project name.

Comment: Now I have manged to download something but it's the loginpage for gitlab...not the actual raw log. I wonder why that is because I point to a jobid that exists.Any suggestions?

Comment: Is your project private?

Comment: Yes it is. Is there a way to add credentials so I can login?

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible through the Gitlab API. It might be possible using  https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/jobs.html#get-a-trace-file .

Comment: Thanks for the info but I dont think I understand how to use this:)

Comment: Gitlab's API is a REST API. Here's a tutorial on how to use REST: https://www.restapitutorial.com/